# Count = true. Works in terraform 11 but not terrafom 12

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform

I'm upgrading to terraform 12 and facing a few issues. We have an autoscaling module (non-root) that calls another module in a central repository (root).
So this module;

```
     module "cef_fleet" {
           source  = "git::ssh://git@github.com/asg-repo.git?ref=terraform12"
           instance_type                            = var.instance_type
           ami                                      = var.ami
           etc ...
```

calls the repository "asg-repo" and in here some resources have a count function such as;

```
resource "aws_autoscaling_schedule" "schedule_stop" {
    count = var.create_resource * var.auto_stop
```

These two variables in the central repository are both set to 'true'. This works with terraform 11 but when I upgraded to 12 I now get the error;

```
    var.create_resource is true
      Unsuitable value for left operand: number required.
```

Is the way to fix this, to simply put replace the true values with 1? Or should it be something like;

```
count = signum(count = var.create_resource * var.auto_start) - where both are also 1?
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a ternary operator:

```
count = var.create_resource && var.auto_start ? 1 : 0
```

Comment: thanks @Dan unfortunately that hasn't worked. The error still persisists but now it does see this ternary operator. This is the error --

count = var.create_resource * var.with_internal_elb ? 1 : 0.

     var.create_resource is true.

Unsuitable value for left operand: number required. --

Both values are in this case are true

Comment: Try using the && operator instead. Answer edited to match this.